# Triangle is $2$-connected or $3$?

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, triangles, graph-connectivity

A connected graph is $k$-connected if either after removing any $k−1$
vertices the remaining graph is connected.

If I follow the definition,triangle is $3$-connected $(k=3)$ since removing any two vertices $(k-1=2)$ leaves a single vertex, which is a connected graph.

But all the places it is showing, it is $2$-connected.

My question is, why triangle is $2$-connected , why it is not $3$-connected?